# Why the ugly code is faster than the pretty code?

Tags: performance-tuning, syntax, compile

**The task**

Consider two tables, `Tab1,Tab2`, that include some real-number data. I need to evaluate the product of some boolean conditions on the value of some function `coordx` that uses the data (an ith row of `Tab1` and a jth row of `Tab2`), and then sum the resulting values over the rows of `Tab1, Tab2`.

Let us consider the following example definitions:

```
Tab1 = Table[{i*Exp[-i^((1/10.))], Sin[i^2.]^2, 1/i^2., (
    1. + 2*i*3*i^2)/i^3, (55. + i^3.1)/i^4}, {i, 1, 10^3}];
Tab2 = Table[{13.*ArcTan[i], 17*Cos[Exp[-i^(1/8.)]], 18. Sin[Sqrt[i]],
     13.*ArcTan[i] + 17*Cos[Exp[-i^(1/8.)]], 13.*ArcTan[i], 
    17*Cos[Exp[-i^(1/8.)]], 18. Sin[Sqrt[i]], 
    13.*ArcTan[i] + 17*Cos[Exp[-i^(1/8.)]], 13.*ArcTan[i], 
    17*Cos[Exp[-i^(1/8.)]], 18. Sin[Sqrt[i]], 
    13.*ArcTan[i] + 17*Cos[Exp[-i^(1/8.)]]}, {i, 1, 10^4, 1}];
coordx[a_, M_, b_] = (
  Abs[a]^M*b + Cos[1.03 b]*Exp[-a])/(a^2 + b^2 + 10^-3)^0.5;
```

**My implementation and its problem**

Let us start with one boolean condition to be summed. So far, I have come up with two different implementations: **"pretty"**,

```
AccPretty = Hold@Compile[{{Tab1, _Real, 2}, {Tab2, _Real, 2}, {xmin, _Real}, {xmax, _Real}, {indexE, _Integer}, {indexE1, _Integer}, {M, _Real}},
  Module[{count, coordx1},
   count = 0;
   Do[
    coordx1 = coordx[Tab1[[i]][[indexE]], M, Tab2[[j]][[indexE1]]];
    count += Boole[xmin < coordx1 < xmax], {i, 1, Length[Tab1]}, {j, 
     1, Length[Tab2]}];
   count/(Length[Tab2] Length[Tab1])
   ], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]/.DownValues@coordx//ReleaseHold
```

and **"ugly"**, where I first compile the boolean condition (as a function of the ith row of `Tab1` and jth row of `Tab2`), and then compile the sum:

```
booleanCondition = 
 Hold@Compile[{{Tab1, _Real, 2}, {Tab2, _Real, 2}, {i, _Integer}, {j, _Integer}, {indexE, _Integer}, {indexE1, _Integer}, {M, _Real}, {xmin, _Real}, {xmax, _Real}}, 
     Boole[xmin < 
       coordx[Tab1[[i]][[indexE]], M, Tab2[[j]][[indexE1]]] < xmax], 
     CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. 
   DownValues@coordx // ReleaseHold
AccUgly = 
 Hold@Compile[{{Tab1, _Real, 2}, {Tab2, _Real, 
       2}, {indexE, _Integer}, {indexE1, _Integer}, {M, _Real}, \
{xmin, _Real}, {xmax, _Real}}, 
     1/(Length[Tab1]*Length[Tab2])
       Sum[booleanCondition[Tab1, Tab2, i, j, indexE, indexE1, M, 
        xmin, xmax], {i, 1, Length[Tab1]}, {j, 1, Length[Tab2]}], 
     CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. 
   DownValues@booleanCondition // ReleaseHold
```

The ugly implementation has a disadvantage that it would quickly become unreadable in the case when many boolean conditions on different quantities have to be imposed.

However, the evaluation of `AccPretty` is longer than `AccUgly`:

```
AccPretty[Tab1, Tab2, 0.1, 2, 1, 2, 5] // AbsoluteTiming
AccUgly[Tab1, Tab2, 0.1, 2, 1, 2, 5] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2.04872, 0.002}

> {1.1129, 0.002}

The difference in timing grows once the complexity of the summation increases. Namely, let us introduce the following acceptances where now *two boolean conditions* have to be evaluated:

```
AccPretty = 
 Hold@Compile[{{Tab1, _Real, 2}, {Tab2, _Real, 
       2}, {xmin, _Real}, {xmax, _Real}, {indexE, _Integer}, \
{indexE1, _Integer}, {M, _Real}}, 
     Module[{count, coordx1, coordx2}, count = 0;
      Do[
       coordx1 = coordx[Tab1[[i]][[indexE]], M, Tab2[[j]][[indexE1]]];
       coordx2 = 
        coordx[Tab1[[i]][[indexE1]], 0.3*M, Tab2[[j]][[indexE]]];
       count += 
        Boole[xmin < coordx1 < xmax && 
          0.5*xmin < coordx2 < 2*xmax], {i, 1, Length[Tab1]}, {j, 1, 
        Length[Tab2]}];
      count/(Length[Tab2]*Length[Tab1])], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
     RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. DownValues@coordx // ReleaseHold
```

and

```
booleanCondition = 
 Hold@Compile[{{Tab1, _Real, 2}, {Tab2, _Real, 
       2}, {i, _Integer}, {j, _Integer}, {indexE, _Integer}, \
{indexE1, _Integer}, {M, _Real}, {xmin, _Real}, {xmax, _Real}}, 
     Boole[xmin < 
        coordx[Tab1[[i]][[indexE]], M, Tab2[[j]][[indexE1]]] < xmax &&
        0.5*xmin < 
        coordx[Tab1[[i]][[indexE1]], 0.3*M, Tab2[[j]][[indexE]]] < 
        2*xmax], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
     RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. DownValues@coordx // ReleaseHold
AccUgly = 
 Hold@Compile[{{Tab1, _Real, 2}, {Tab2, _Real, 
       2}, {xmin, _Real}, {xmax, _Real}, {indexE, _Integer}, \
{indexE1, _Integer}, {M, _Real}}, 
     1/(Length[Tab1]*Length[Tab2])
       Sum[booleanCondition[Tab1, Tab2, i, j, indexE, indexE1, M, 
        xmin, xmax], {i, 1, Length[Tab1]}, {j, 1, Length[Tab2]}], 
     CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. 
   DownValues@booleanCondition // ReleaseHold
```

Now, the difference in performance is almost 4x!

```
AccPretty[Tab1, Tab2, 0.1, 2, 1, 2, 5] // AbsoluteTiming
AccUgly[Tab1, Tab2, 0.1, 2, 1, 2, 5] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {4.08982, 0.0010118}

> {1.14582, 0.0010118}

Probably the reason can be traced to the necessity of defining two coordinates `coordx1`, `coordx2`, and not to evaluating two boolean conditions. This means that I define them inefficiently.

**The question**

I want to keep `AccPretty` instead of `AccUgly` given the transparency of the former, but the performance is essential. What may be a general reason for the slower evaluation of `AccPretty` (assuming it does not depend on the specific example)?

Comment: Please provide a complete, working example in your question so that others can try to investigate the issue without having to waste time on guessing valid inputs.

Comment: @LukasLang : done.

Comment: @LukasLang : I have also updated the question body with some investigation on how by adding mode boolean conditions we would increase the difference in the performance of ugly and pretty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you use

```
coordx1 = coordx[Tab1[[i]][[indexE]], M, Tab2[[j]][[indexE1]]];
```

instead of

```
coordx1 = coordx[Tab1[[i, indexE]], M, Tab2[[j, indexE1]]];
```

This causes frequent calls to `CopyTensor` that slow everthing down. (You can see this when you look at the pseudocode produced by `` CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint[AccPretty] ``.) I was actually very surprised that this happened! And for some reason that I don't understand, this happens here, but not in `booleanCondition`...

Anyways, the modified version is twice as fast as `AccUgly`. You can squeeze out quite a lot more by using

```
coordx1 =  coordx[Compile`GetElement[Tab1, i, indexE], M,  Compile`GetElement[Tab2, j, indexE1]];
```

instead. This (together with the option `RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"`) deactivates the bound checks during the indexing.

Btw., we can simply parallelize the counting by defining the following function:

```
AccPretty3 = 
 Hold@Compile[{{Tab1, _Real, 1}, {Tab2, _Real, 
       2}, {xmin, _Real}, {xmax, _Real}, {indexE, _Integer}, {indexE1, _Integer}, {M, _Real}},
     Module[{count, coordx1},
      count = 0;
      Do[
       coordx1 = coordx[Compile`GetElement[Tab1, indexE], M, 
         Compile`GetElement[Tab2, j, indexE1]];
       count += Boole[xmin < coordx1 < xmax]
       , {j, 1, Length[Tab2]}];
      
      count
      ],
     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     RuntimeOptions -> "Speed",
     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
     Parallelization -> True
     
     ] /. DownValues@coordx // ReleaseHold
```

and then running

```
Total[AccPretty3[Tab1, Tab2, 0.1, 2, 1, 2, 5]] / N[Length[Tab1] Length[Tab2]]
```

On my 8 core machine, this is about 75 times faster than the original version of `AccPretty`.

**Edit**

You want to count only some `i` you can introduce `i` as additional argument:

```
AccPretty4 = Hold@Compile[{{Tab1, _Real, 2}, {Tab2, _Real, 2},
      {i, _Integer},
      {xmin, _Real}, {xmax, _Real}, {indexE, _Integer}, {indexE1, _Integer}, {M, _Real}}, Module[{count, coordx1}, 
      count = 0;
      Do[
       coordx1 = 
        coordx[Compile`GetElement[Tab1, i, indexE], M, 
         Compile`GetElement[Tab2, j, indexE1]];
       count += Boole[xmin < coordx1 < xmax], {j, 1, Length[Tab2]}];
      count],
     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     RuntimeOptions -> "Speed",
     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
     Parallelization -> True
     ] /. DownValues@coordx // ReleaseHold
```

Then you can run, for example, this:

```
AccPretty4[Tab1, Tab2, Range[begin, end], 0.1, 2, 1, 2, 5]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! How do you think, is it possible to adapt `AccPretty3` to the case when I do not need to sum over all rows of `Tab1`, but only over some of them (say from i1 to i2)?

Comment: Ah I see; there is nothing special in adopting. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. Please see my edit.